# how to get DISTINCT ID values in PHP/MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have PHP code to fetch 2 tables "tbl_products" and "tbl_productphotos" data from database.I want to fetch DISTINCT data. 
My query and code is :

```
<?php
$sql = "select DISTINCT t1.*,t2.photo 
        from tbl_products t1, tbl_productphotos t2 
        where t1.ProductID = t2.ProductID 
        and t1.tilename = 'Glass Tile' 
        and t1.ProductID = t2.ProductID 
        ORDER BY ProductID DESC";
$qex=mysql_query($sql); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qex))
{
?> 

    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['ProductID'];?>">
    <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 isotope-item websites" style="float: left">
    <div class="portfolio-item">
        <span class="thumb-info thumb-info-lighten thumb-info-bottom-info thumb-info-centered-icons">
        <span class="thumb-info-wrapper">

        <img src="images/products/thumbs/<?php echo $row['photo']; ?>"  class="img-responsive" alt="" height="200px" width="200px">
        <span class="thumb-info-title">
        <span class="thumb-info-inner"><?php echo $row['Title'];?></span>
        <span class="thumb-info-type"><?php echo substr($row['Description'],0 ,37);?></span>
        </span>
        <span class="thumb-info-action">
        <a href="glass-tile-details.php?ProductID=<?php echo base64_encode($row['ProductID']); ?> &quot;&amp;&lt;&nbsp; &Atilde;&Chi;!&upsih;&upsilon; &quot;&amp;&gt;&euro; &nbsp;&Aacute;&Acirc;&quot;&amp; &acute;&AElig;&copy;&quot;&amp;&amp; &quot;&Eacute;&piv;&Pi; 1&quot;&amp;&thetasym;&Theta; &quot;&amp;"><span class="thumb-info-action-icon thumb-info-action-icon-primary"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></span>
        </a> 

        <a href="images/products/thumbs/<?php echo $row['photo']; ?>" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" class="lightbox-portfolio">
        <span class="thumb-info-action-icon thumb-info-action-icon-light"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></span>
        </a>
        </span>
        </span>
        </span>
    </div>
    </li>
<?php
}
?>
```

tables are :  tbl_products

```
ProductID      Title     Description     titlename
35             ABC       tile           Glass Tile
36             XYZ       tile 2          Glass Tile
```

2nd table : "tbl_productphotos"

```
id      ProductID          photo        Each Image store in 3 folders
5         35            image.jpeg   (in folder big,medium,thumbs)
6         35            image.jpeg   (in folder big,medium,thumbs)
7         35            image.jpeg   (in folder big,medium,thumbs)
8         36            image.jpeg   (in folder big,medium,thumbs)
9         36            image.jpeg   (in folder big,medium,thumbs)
10        36            image.jpeg   (in folder big,medium,thumbs)
```

we can select multiple images i select 3 images and all 3 images stored in all three folders. so i just want to get only one image with details with one ProductID but i showns me all 3 images on the web page.

Please check & reply & help me.
Thanks & Regards 
Ankit

Comment: `asap`? I don't recall you hiring anyone. We are not your work monkeys.

Comment: `t2.photo` is the same in all the rows. You shouldn't get 3 copies of it. Are they supposed to be different photos? If they are, which one should it return?

Comment: sorry sir, i am new user here from now will never write this asap. Regards- Ankit

Comment: You don't need to have `t1.ProductID = t2.ProductID` twice in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Use `GROUP BY t1.productid` instead of `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: sir when i fill one form there i can select multiple images for one entry & sometimes i select 2  and sometimes 3 and save them. and on the web page where i want to show all the  data from the database there i want to get only one row content with one photo, But i get 3 images on the web page with exactly same title name tile name & same description . i just want to display only one image from any of the images folders. because all the images stored in all of the 3 folders. Regards - Ankit

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding select * .
(and you  have two time the condition   t1.ProductID = t2.ProductID )

```
$sql = "select DISTINCT 
            t1.ProductID, 
            t1.Title,
            t1.titlename,
            t1.Description,
            t2.photo 
        from tbl_products t1
        INNER JOIN  tbl_productphotos t2 on t1.ProductID = t2.ProductID 
        and t1.tilename = 'Glass Tile' 
        ORDER BY t1.ProductID DESC";
```

Comment: sorry its not working even with this query i get blank screen.

Comment: update your question and add  the  exact  query code you are uning now ..please  .. anc check for error and related  message .. i have also update  the answer for avoid ambiguity in order by column